# Deleted products from woocommerce are still in the database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, mysql, phpmyadmin

I deleted some product variations from my Woocommerce website. almost 75% of all the product variations on my website. I had 20,000 products with 640,000 variations. and now i have only 180,000 variations. I was trying to lower the size of the database but unfortunately after deleting all that, it still hasn't changed the database. the database is still 2.5GB.

Is there a way to delete the specific variations that i already deleted in phpmyadmin too.

I appreciate y'all's time :)

Comment: You seem to be describing two problems? one is that variations don't appear to be deleted when you try to delete them (though, you also say the number of variations has reduced?). The other is that the DB size isn't reducing. The latter could be to do with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646373/mysql-data-file-wont-shrink

Comment: Hey Dan, You're right. what i wrote was a little confusing. My problem actually is the second one that i deleted the products variations but they are still in the database!! thanks for the link man!! :)